# Youtube Data Api - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setApiKey' of undefined

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I search music with youtube data api. I use javascript and jquery and i have a problem.
Here is my code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo SITE_PUBLIC; ?>/bootstrap-3.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>

<script>
function keyWordsearch(){
    gapi.client.setApiKey('myapikey');
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
            data = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "data": [{"name":"eminem"},{"name":"shakira"}] }' );
            $.each(data["data"], function( index, value ) {
                makeRequest(value["name"]);
            });

    });
    }
    function makeRequest(q) {
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: q,
                part: 'snippet', 
                maxResults: 10
        });
        request.execute(function(response)  {                                                                                    
                $('#results').empty()
                var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                vidTitle = item.snippet.title;  
                vidThumburl =  item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;                 
                vidThumbimg = '<pre><img id="thumb" src="'+vidThumburl+'" alt="No  Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"></pre>';                   

                $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + vidThumbimg +  '</pre>');                      
        })  
    })  
}   
keyWordsearch();
</script>
```

This code not working. Chrome console say "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setApiKey' of undefined". But this code is working: 
keyWordsearch() to

```
$(document).click(function(){
        keyWordsearch()
})
```

I do not understand this issue. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My code run on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kk1s6nds/).But not run my html file. My html file is here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Search</title>


  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Search Results</h1>
      <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>        
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>   
    <script>
     $(function(){
     function keyWordsearch(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCWzGO9Vo1eYOW4R4ooPdoFLmNk6zkc0Jw');
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                data = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "data": [{"name":"eminem"}] }' );
                $.each(data["data"], function( index, value ) {
                    makeRequest(value["name"]);
                });

        });
}
    function makeRequest(q) {
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: q,
                part: 'snippet', 
                maxResults: 10
        });
        request.execute(function(response)  {                                                                                    
                $('#results').empty()
                var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                vidTitle = item.snippet.title;  
                vidThumburl =  item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;                 
                vidThumbimg = '<pre><img id="thumb" src="'+vidThumburl+'" alt="No  Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"></pre>';                   

                $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + vidThumbimg +  '</pre>');                      
        })  
    })  
}
    keyWordsearch();
     })
  </script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gapi.client is undefined (null).  Go make it not be null.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, you haven't load the javascript library. That's why it can't find the reference.
You can add it like:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an initial function while calling the API like this: `client.js?onload=init` (see my example below). Besides no need of a doucument.ready() wrapper. I'm not sure why it works with your API key on my local machine but I guess it's some kind of magic that checks if the site is availible to the public - if true the referrer entries in your google account will get important - correct me on that if somebody knows whats exactly happening here.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function makeRequest(q) {
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
          q: q,
          part: 'snippet',
          maxResults: 3
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
          $('#results').empty();
          var resultItems = response.result.items;
          $.each(resultItems, function(index, item) {
            vidTitle = item.snippet.title;
            vidThumburl =  item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
            vidThumbimg = '<pre><img id="thumb" src="'+vidThumburl+'" alt="No  Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"></pre>';
            $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + vidThumbimg +  '</pre>');
          });
        });
      }

      function init() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCWzGO9Vo1eYOW4R4ooPdoFLmNk6zkc0Jw');
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
          data = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "data": [{"name":"orsons"}] }' );
          $.each(data["data"], function(index, value) {
            makeRequest(value["name"]);
          });
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>YouTube API 3.0 Test</h1>
    <ul id="results"></ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the answers which explain that you must specify and provide a callback function for the Google API client `<script>` loading line, I'd like to point out that it seems that the `onload` parameter will never run the specified function (at least in Chrome) when you load the Google API client.js from a local file (even though you are serving the HTML page via a webserver and not loading it from the file-system, which apparently seemed to be the only gotcha with the Google API JS client...).

e.g.:

```
<script src="/lib/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Although `client.js` will be loaded, this will never launch the `handleClientLoad` function when it's finished loading. I thought it would be useful to point this out, as this was a really frustrating thing to debug.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

This MUST be called at the end, or at least after you define your method "handleClientLoad". This is its callback, and only after it was called - it means google api is ready. This is why you get gapi.client is null.

For the fun of it, you can use a timeout of a few seconds before using gapi.client and see it is not null anymore.