# Copied example from documentation of Youtube API not working

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to search for a video with some words using Youtube API and I have run my example on this interactive app https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22q%22%3A%22ay%20vamos%22%7D. I have copied the source code on that page and removed authorization because I don't need it and filled credentials. This is the error I keep on getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'youtube' of undefined`

```js
<body>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

    <script>
        /**
         * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.search.list
         * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
         * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
         */

        function loadClient() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey("-------------------");
            return gapi.client
                .load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
                .then(
                    function () {
                        return gapi.client.youtube.search
                            .list({
                                part: ["snippet"],
                                q: "ay vamos",
                            })
                            .then(
                                function (response) {
                                    // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                                    console.log("Response", response);
                                },
                                function (err) {
                                    console.error("Execute error", err);
                                }
                            );
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err);
                    }
                );
        }
        // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
    </script>
    <button onclick="loadClient()">execute</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I solved this problem by adding a tag that I got from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492954/youtube-data-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setapikey-of-undef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cannot read propery 'youtube' of undefined" hints that `gapi.client` isn't defined properly. I ran your code myself and printing `gapi.client` to the console outputs `null`.

Also, I couldn't find anything that is calling your `loadClient()` function which looks like it is responsible for actually loading the youtube client? That could be a separate issue.

Comment: Okay now I changed it but now I get setApiKey is undefined, should i use this and option 2? https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md

Comment: You are missing the `gapi.load('client', start);` line from Option 2.

Comment: But loadClient() returns gapi.client.load isn't that the same thing

Comment: Now the error is "Cannot read property 'setApiKey' of undefined" - which is just the same root issue that `gapi.client` is undefined.